# Prestashop configuration multishop

Tags: prestashop

i have to migrate from prestashop 1.6 to prestashop 1.7, in the new version i have made a multishop site. 
how should I set the httpd.conf and the conf file of the related site for it to work?
now my conf site file is:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin name@example.com
        ServerName www.example.it
    ServerAlias example.it
        DocumentRoot /home/sites/www.example.it/web/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/sites/www.example.it/web/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        RewriteEngine on
        #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}              !^/.well-known/ [NC]
        #RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
       #RewriteOptions inherit
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.it/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.it/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.it/chain.pem
        ServerAdmin name@example.com
        ServerName www.example.it
    ServerAlias example.it
        DocumentRoot /home/sites/www.example.it/web
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/sites/www.example.it/web>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"
php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/sites/www.example.it:/home/sites/www.example.it/private:/home/sites/www.example.it/tmp:/tmp"
php_admin_value session.save_path "/home/sites/www.example.it/tmp"
php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp"
php_admin_value sendmail_path] "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@example.it"
php_admin_value max_input_vars 10500
php_admin_value memory_limit 512M
php_admin_value max_execution_time 44000
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 512M
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteOptions inherit
    <Directory /home/sites/*/web>
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What should I add or change in this file?
is there any other file I need to change?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change your server's virtual host when turning on multishop option. Do you have some problems with the configuration ?